# scaling pictures with carrierwave and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i am uploading images with carrierwave through active admin. my model is call Gallery and on the form. i want users to be able to select a size in the form and carrierwave to crop it on the server site. is there a way to implement this with carrierwave

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this, is using MiniMagic.

Carrierwave has a "versions". If I'm correct, this allows you to create conditionals in order to upload differente images sizes.

Other option:

Remember that carrierwave use independent uploaders. Using each uploader you can define independent images sizes.

So, when the user select 200x200, you will use the uploader that will have that specific size.

The only thing, is that you will have many uploaders. For now, is something that can work, but maybe you can try with the first option

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Get-image-dimensions

Comment: how will i assign uploader base on what the user selected in the form?

Comment: Remember each uploader needs to match with the field in the form. "image_1" will match with "mount uploader image_1".

So, when the user select that field, you will use that specific uploader.

Comment: The other option. You can use any gem for "crop". In that case, each option the user select, will match with default "cropping option". 

This is just an idea, but give it a try if you think can help you

Comment: am looking into jcrop. how can i have specific value users can set instead of dynamic selecting